# Button group height not matching input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an bootstrap input group and my button to the right of my input does not match in height. I have reviewed the examples on getbootstrap and I don't see what I am doing wrong. How can I get my button height to match my text input?  Below is the html I am using and a screen shot showing the height difference.  I get the same result on firefox 33.1 and chrome 38.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 text-left id-form-data">
<form id="partsearch" method="GET" action="">
<div class="input-group" style="width:200px;">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="partNumber" id="partNumber" placeholder="Part#" maxlength="12" required>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine in the latest Bootstrap. Upgrade to 3.3.1

Comment: Thanks for response.  I am using 3.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

By adding nbsp; next to my glyph, it solved my problem.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer inserts space. Use a completely invisible character instead: `&zwnj;`. This has the same effect:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
&zwnj;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</button>
```

Read more about it here [Invisible Delimiter for Strings in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812253/invisible-delimiter-for-strings-in-html)